# Can I parallelize image processing with PLINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, image-processing, gdi+, plinq

I want to compare the alpha channel from one image to ~1000 other images. My compare method looks like this:

```
public static unsafe double Similiarity (Bitmap a, Bitmap b)
{
    BitmapData aData = a.LockBits (
        new Rectangle (0, 0, a.Width, a.Height), 
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, a.PixelFormat);
    BitmapData bData = b.LockBits (
        new Rectangle (0, 0, b.Width, b.Height), 
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, b.PixelFormat);
    int PixelSize = 4;

    double sum = 0;
    for (int y=0; y<aData.Height; y++) {
        byte* aRow = (byte *)aData.Scan0 + (y * aData.Stride);
        byte* bRow = (byte *)bData.Scan0 + (y * bData.Stride);
        for (int x=0; x<aData.Width; x++) {
            byte aWeight = aRow [x * PixelSize + 3];
            byte bWeight = bRow [x * PixelSize + 3];
            sum += Math.Abs (aWeight - bWeight);
        }
    }
    a.UnlockBits (aData);
    b.UnlockBits (bData);

    return 1 - ((sum / 255) / (a.Width * a.Height));
}
```

I thought the simplest way to speed up the computation would be by using PLINQ:

```
var list = from Bitmap img in imageList.AsParallel where (Similiarity (referenceImage, img) > 0.5) select img;
```

But on execution there is an Exception in gdiplus:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The operation is invalid [GDI+ status: Win32Error]
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus.CheckStatus (Status status) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Bitmap.LockBits (Rectangle rect, ImageLockMode flags, PixelFormat format, System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bitmapData) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I understand that gdiplus must be executed in different processes, but I thought PLINQ is doing so. What is wrong with my assumptions?

Comment: PLINQ certainly isn't using different processes for execution. It's using threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to separate weight calculation from similarity comparison like this:

```
public static unsafe byte[,] GetWeight(Bitmap a)
{
    BitmapData aData = a.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, a.Width, a.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, a.PixelFormat);
    const int pixelSize = 4;

    byte[,] weight = new byte[aData.Width, aData.Height];
    for (int y = 0; y < aData.Height; y++)
    {
        byte* aRow = (byte*)aData.Scan0 + (y * aData.Stride);
        for (int x = 0; x < aData.Width; x++)
        {
            byte aWeight = aRow[x * pixelSize + 3];
            weight[x, y] = aWeight;
        }
    }
    a.UnlockBits(aData);
    return weight;
}

public static double GetSimilarity(byte[,] weightsA, byte[,] weightsB)
{
    double sum = 0;
    int height = weightsA.GetLength(1);
    int width = weightsA.GetLength(0);
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            byte aWeight = weightsA[x,y];
            byte bWeight = weightsB[x, y];
            sum += Math.Abs(aWeight - bWeight);
        }
    }

    return 1 - ((sum / 255) / (width * height));
}
```

The call itself will then look like this:

```
var referenceWeigth = GetWeight(referenceImage);    
var list =
        imageList
            .AsParallel()
            .Select(image => new {@Image = image, @Weight = GetWeight(image)})
            .Where(imageAndWeight => GetSimilarity(imageAndWeight.Weight, referenceWeigth) > 0.5)
            .Select(imageAndWeight => imageAndWeight.Image);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggested code. It works as expected and also enhanced my understanding of LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be that you try to lock the same bits in different threads at the same time. A possible solution (as you are only reading) should be to first extract the bits from each bitmap and only use those arrays to parallel compare them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see with this is that while `img` is taken from a list, the `referenceImage` is the same instance being used in multiple threads, each of which are trying to lock it.

Consider locking the reference image outside, and passing the BitmapData.